# Trying to replicate android homescreen Contact shortcuts, with issues

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, quickcontact

Okay, I'm trying to replicate the shortcuts which get placed on the homescreen when creating a contact shortcut, example shown:

[image]

I've got a working QuickContactBadge, which when clicked shows the QuickContact toolbar. However, I have two things I'm having trouble with.

One is the picture. I tried using the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610786/contacts-quey-with-name-and-picture-uri) (I altered it by adding a parameter to pass in the contact ID). I then assign the image to my QuickContactBadge as so:

```
bdg.setImageURI(getPhotoUri(cid));
```

It definitely gets pictures, but it is getting TOTALLY the wrong picture. As illustrated here:

[image]

As you can see, the image it returned for Domino's is clearly NOT the Domino's logo.

I'm getting my contact ID to pass to the function from this code:

```
    public static String[] ContactsProjection = new String[] {
            Contacts._ID,
            Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, 
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    };

    public static Cursor getContacts() {
            ContentResolver cr = CoreLib.ContentResolver();
            Cursor contacts = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                    ContactsProjection, 
                    null, null, 
                    Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED + " DESC"
            );
        return contacts;
    }
```

Which I believe should be returning me the proper ID for each record. Yes?

Next how do I get exactly the thumbnail shrunk or cropped as the shortcut shows it?

I was a little disappointed to see that the QuickContactBadge doesn't actually replicate the whole look and feel of the QuickContact shortcut, ... but just acts as in invocation target for the QuickContact card. Is there any built in way to easily replicate the contact shortcut in it's entirety, invocation, image, text and all, without needing to reproduce the whole thing from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah HAH! Figured out how to get the correct photo. While this seems counter-intuitive, when building your field projection to query the contacts, the fields `Contacts._ID` and `ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID` are not the same thing.

`ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID` is the correct one to pass in to get the photo. Use this, and everything is now golden.